# Is there a specific problem that is in both NP and co-NP but not in P?

Tags: complexity-theory, np

A problem is in NP if a correct answer to it can be verified to be so in polynomial time.

A problem is in co-NP if an incorrect answer to it can be verified to be so in polynomial time.

P is a subset of the intersection of the sets NP and co-NP.

My question is: what is a **specific** problem that is in the intersection of co-NP & NP, but is not in P?

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/34889/a-language-complete-for-np-intersection-co-np

Comment: Your definition of co-NP is incorrect. For example, you can easily verify that a proposed satisfying assignment to a Boolean formula actually makes the formula false but that doesn't mean that SAT is in co-NP.

Comment: Dude, there is no need to shout. You do not need stars and all-capitals in your title.

Comment: Stop rolling back people's edits when they fix your post. There's no markup in titles.

Comment: I wrote the following par. initially as addition to the Q. i'm writing the exact same text as a comment upon David Richerby's edit&removal:
"This Q has been bullied by Gilles, who, as i eventually found out is a moderator here, on some format considerations 
that seemed to his judgement to be crucial to the quality of the site here. from what i see (no clue to anything else), 
he followed some "insightful" directions of some other user(s) that paralleled 
his senses and concerns. the other user(s) can be seen on the comment lines by any pair of eyes with basic senses. "

Comment: @ashley Your question is not the place to complain about how you feel you are being mistreated. If you feel that your question is being treated unfairly, take the issue up on [meta](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/). (Participation on meta requires reputation at least 5, which you have.)

Comment: @ashley You are wrong. Gilles and others have helped getting your post into shape according to network and [cs.SE] policies and best practice. If you are not ready to accept said standards (one is, "be nice"), you are not welcome here. Should you continue to vandalise this post -- even if it's your own -- action *will* be taken. You have been warned.

Answer (score 6):

An answer to your question would be a problem $p$ which is in $\mathop{NP}\cap\mathop{coNP}$, and thus in $\mathop{NP}$, but not in $P$. Existence of such a problem would easily imply $P\neq\mathop{NP}$, which is a seriously open problem to this date. That is to say, no one can answer your question yet.

Comment: The question is, can we exhibit an explicit problem $L$ in NP$\cap$coNP such that $L \in P$ implies P=NP. For example, SAT is in NP, and if SAT$\in$P then P=NP.

Comment: That's an interesting question, and sdcvvc's link gives an answer to that.

Comment: @Untitled That's a quick answer. A worthy way of looking into the 
intractability of the problems is from the angle of "what we know so far." 
Check out the NPI "zone" i noted in my Q for a broader angle for you.

Comment: @ashley I can't find it. Do you have a link?

Comment: @Untitled - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-intermediate.

Comment: @Untitled sdcvvc's link doesn't answer my question. Let me rephrase it. Suppose that P$\neq$NP. Does it follow that NP$\cap$coNP$\setminus$P$\neq \emptyset$?

Comment: There's nothing suggesting that NP∩coNP∖P is necessarily empty-- according to CLRS for one thing. This is one of the questions open for further work.